# Problems with arm-none-eabi linker in Eclipse using GNU MCU Eclipse Plugin

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, arm, stm32

I am having a problem with a project that I'm trying to set up for my new STM32F7 Nucleo Board. I freshly installed the [GNU ARM Embedded toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded), [STM32CubeF7](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef7.html) and the [GNU MCU Eclipse Plugin](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/), with which I set up a new Project on my Windows 7 machine at work. I have previously done that at home on my Ubuntu Laptop without issues.
After I set up the project, I added the HAL and the CMSIS libraries and used a template project from STM32CubeF7. So far the compilation works fine, but when linking I get the following error:

```
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.4 2016q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lc_p-lc_p
```

To my understanding the issue here is that some library with a very strange name can not be found. Unfortunately the only [page that I found where the same error is described](https://www.kharkovforum.com/showthread.php?t=3532032) is in Russian, which I don't speak at all.

At first glance, to me it looks like the generated makefile is corrupted, and a library called c_p is trying to be linked, but it is done twice without a space in between. So it could be an issue with Eclipse or the Eclipse GNU MCU Plugin.

**Things that I tried to get rid of the error:**

- Update Eclipse
- Downgrade to several old versions of the GNU ARM Embedded toolchain
- Turn off/on the following linker options:

  - `--specs=nano.specs`
  - `-nodefaultlibs`
  - `-nostdlib`
- Install the toolchain in a folder without any spaces

Here's the automatically generated makefile:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include system/src/subdir.mk
-include system/HAL/Src/subdir.mk
-include system/subdir.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(ASM_DEPS)),)
-include $(ASM_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(S_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(S_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
SECONDARY_FLASH += \
stm32Template.hex \

SECONDARY_SIZE += \
stm32Template.siz \


# All Target
all: stm32Template.elf secondary-outputs

# Tool invocations
stm32Template.elf: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C++ Linker'
    arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra  -g3 -p -pg -T mem.ld -T libs.ld -T sections.ld -nostartfiles -L"../ldscripts" -Wl,-Map,"stm32Template.map" --specs=nano.specs -o "stm32Template.elf" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

stm32Template.hex: stm32Template.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: GNU ARM Cross Create Flash Image'
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "stm32Template.elf"  "stm32Template.hex"
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

stm32Template.siz: stm32Template.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: GNU ARM Cross Print Size'
    arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "stm32Template.elf"
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(CC_DEPS)$(C++_DEPS)$(OBJS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS)$(CXX_DEPS)$(SECONDARY_FLASH)$(SECONDARY_SIZE)$(ASM_DEPS)$(S_UPPER_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS) stm32Template.elf
    -@echo ' '

secondary-outputs: $(SECONDARY_FLASH) $(SECONDARY_SIZE)

.PHONY: all clean dependents

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Does anybody have any inputs with this for me?

**EDIT:**
GNU MCU Eclipse Plugin provides a template for new projects, even with this I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I figured out how to work around this problem, yet unfortunately I have not yet found out what exactly causes it. I searched my `GNU ARM Embedded toolchain` install folder and did not find any library name containing `c_p`. I figured the cause to this problem must be lying wherever the default libraries of the linker are defined, which is why I assume the problem lies within the toolchain itself.

However, I chose to disable the use of default libraries (`-nodefaultlibs` flag) and linked them myself. I linked the following libraries:

`-lg -lstdc++ -lgcc -lm -lrdimon -lc`

**If someone can help me find the actual root of this problem that would be greatly appreciated.**
However, since it solved my problem, I am going to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You make one very important mistake. You try to use DIY Eclipse configuration to import projects created for the particular environment.

Install OpenSTM32.
Generate your project using SW4STM32 toolchain setting.

Import the project. Compile, link and debug

If you find the installed toolchain obsolete, you will be able to replace it.

Comment: I did not import any settings, I just copied the source files so that I can set up and configure the project myself. I did that at home and it worked for another project - but on Linux. The thing is that I would like to keep using Eclipse, as I have been doing for quite a few years. And I would like to know why this happens, so that I'll know where the issue lies, whether it's the toolchain or the IDE.

Comment: Ok. Sorry mate.

Comment: No worries at all, thanks for trying to help :) I just updated my question, the same error occurs when I create a clean new project and try to compile it. the project is from a template that the GNU MCU Eclipse Plugin provides, so it can not be because I copied files into the project. I fear it has to do with the Toolchain...

Comment: If you want to know and understand - create your own makefile for the particular project. Otherwise it is just waste of time to analyse automaticly generated makefiles. OpenSTM32 ones (it is eclipse) works with no problems and it is supported by STM. I use this environment for 99% of my projects - and do not use HAL or SPL (only bare register)

Comment: except some very low level projects (better called hacks)

Comment: Yes you're right, that would be the best approach to finding the issue. I will do that.

Comment: Thanks again for your inputs, I found a way to avoid this and will close the issue. Yet unfortunately I wasn't able to find the root of it. I posted my answer above.